# How to change the codes order in pandas categorical data type?

Tags: pandas, categorical-data

I am working on the creation of codes for clients and I am interested in knowing if I can modify the order of the created code index.

```py
    import pandas as pd

    data = {
        'dates' : ['2018-01-02T11:55:54', '2018-01-02T13:31:52',
           '2018-01-02T13:34:38', '2018-01-02T13:38:30',
           '2018-01-02T13:44:06'],
        'clients' : ['peter', 'arnold','beto', 'peter', 'brandon']

    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out:
    dates   clients
0   2018-01-02T11:55:54 peter
1   2018-01-02T13:31:52 arnold
2   2018-01-02T13:34:38 beto
3   2018-01-02T13:38:30 peter
4   2018-01-02T13:44:06 brandon
```

I tried to sort the dataset by date first and then create the categorical code index, but it didn't work...

```
df.dates = pd.to_datetime( df.dates )
#sorting df by date:
df.sort_values('dates', inplace = True)


df.clients = pd.Categorical( df.clients )
df['client_code'] = df.clients.cat.codes
```

I expected the result to be the 'codes' index sorted by client registration date, but it was not the case.

Expected outcome:

```py
    dates   clients client_code
0   2018-01-02 11:55:54 peter   0
1   2018-01-02 13:31:52 arnold  1
2   2018-01-02 13:34:38 beto    2
3   2018-01-02 13:38:30 peter   0
4   2018-01-02 13:44:06 brandon 3
```

outcome:

```py
    dates   clients client_code
0   2018-01-02 11:55:54 peter   3
1   2018-01-02 13:31:52 arnold  0
2   2018-01-02 13:34:38 beto    1
3   2018-01-02 13:38:30 peter   3
4   2018-01-02 13:44:06 brandon 2
```

Please help, and thanks for reading...

Comment: Can you add your expected output? Also in the form of a dataframe. Or in this case just a list, since you want categories.

Comment: Do you want `df['client_code'] = pd.factorize(df['clients'])`?

Comment: i just updated the question.
Thanks for answering! You're totally right that was all i needed.
Thank you very much